# update plain text after change it to a textbox

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, textbox

I have some records from a database that are shown in table rows and columns.
I show this information in plain text. But I want change them to a text box whenever a user clicks them, and update the contents as the cursor is blurred.
I hope I could give my mean.

Is there anybody to help me ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show us some code, maybe an attempt you have made? Also what language are you using for server side coding, so that we can point you to a useful resource?

Comment: @Mohammad try posting some code its hard to understand what you want and maybe code would help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are references to sites and/or projects to help you accomplish your task.

http://www.mysqlajaxtableeditor.com/

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3104-PHP-Edit-data-in-an-HTML-table-using-AJAX.html

http://www.9lessons.info/2011/03/live-table-edit-with-jquery-and-ajax.html

Comment: Thank you George. you are right, I did not mention what languages I have used. My project is running with PHP and MySQL. The 3rd link was what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

To turn the contents of a table cell into a test input:

```
//bind event handler to click event for all table cells
$('td').on('click', function () {

    //cache this table cell in a variable
    var $table_cell = $(this);

    //add a text input with the text of this table cell,
    //then select that text input, focus it (so the user doesn't have to click on the text box to gain focus),
    //then add an event handler to the text input for the blur event
    $table_cell.html('<input type="text" value="' + $table_cell.text() + '" />').children('input').focus().bind('blur', function () {

        //run your code to update the text within this <td> element

        //sent a POST request to your server-side script with the value of the text-input
        $.post('path_to/server/script.php', $(this).serialize(), function (response) {

            //here you get the response from the server and you can update the table cell
            //if the response from the server is the new text for the cell then you can do this...
            $table_cell.text(response);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for inline editing, there are plenty of plugins available.

This one looks promising http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable (haven't tried it)